# Hyperledger fabric make peer not running

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

On Windows, inside Vagrant, I am trying to run `make peer` in `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric`.

I am getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the command:

```
make peer
```

Try these :

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest

docker pull hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc:latest
```

to pull the latest images published by the Hyperledger fabric project from DockerHub.

Answer (score 0):

It says latest tag is not found for the base image. Looks like a Fabric bug at that point of time, and I reckon that this issue would have got solved by now.

If not, pull the image yourself manually. And tag it yourself as latest
For E.g,

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:x86_64-0.1.0 
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:x86_64-0.1.0 hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:latest
```